# Rails strong params for creating multiple objects from one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create multiple objects of the same model from one form. Params which I get in my `create` method look like this:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"objects"=> <ActionController::Parameters {
  "0"=>{priority"=>"24", "style"=>"three_pictures"}, 
  "1"=>{"priority"=>"24", "style"=>"three_pictures"}, 
  "2"=>{"priority"=>"24", "style"=>"three_pictures"}
} permitted: false>}permitted: false>
```

I am confused about using `strong params` in this case. My `create` method looks like this:

```
def create
  params[:objects].each do |index, object|
    Object.create(object.permit(:priority, :style))
  end
  ...
end
```

This works, but doesn't look like the right way to do this. How should this be done?

Comment: I think its the right way of doing it if you don't want to bypass mass assignment security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I need a bit more info here. When I create more than 1 record at a time its usually a chield of another object and mine looks like this

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def family_params
  params.require(:family).permit(:name, users_attributes: [ :name, :email ])
end
```

I hope that this helps.

Happy Hacking :)